# Why is video player working here and not there

Tags: reactjs, video, tracking

I made a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/greta100-masonry-video-not-showing-1z9vo?file=/src/components/drivers/video-viewer.jsx) showing the problem. In the Sandbox the Video player is working but replacing the code with below code is not working. If I move the  `src={filePa..` to `<video..` then it works but without caption dunno

I write this code and it works:

```
return (
    <div className="pg-driver-view">
        <div className="video-container">
            {this.renderLoading()}
            <video
                style={{ visibility }}
                controls
                type={`video/${fileType}`}
                onCanPlay={e => this.onCanPlay(e)}
                src={filePath}
            >
                Video playback is not supported by your browser.
            </video>
            
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

Then I try this and it's not working the player does not show no warning no messages in the log:

```
return (
    <div className="pg-driver-view">
        <div className="video-container">
            {this.renderLoading()}
            <video style={{ visibility }} controls onCanPlay={e => this.onCanPlay(e)}>
                Video playback is not supported by your browser.
                <source src={filePath} type={`video/${fileType}`} />
                <track src="test_captions_en.vtt" kind="captions" srcLang="en" label="hello_english_captions" />
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

Any idea?

Comment: can you share your full component code ? because i tried in a sandbox and both works fine

Comment: Thanks @MohammadFaisal here's a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/greta100-masonry-video-not-showing-1z9vo?file=/src/components/drivers/video-viewer.jsx) showing what works. It dose not have the "not working" version code I show in my question. Scroll down you see the video playing alright. But when I add the not working code "from my question above" it does not work. Sorry this is a large project much files...